# How to start activityindicator when a alert is popped up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app i need to show an alert that navigating to next screen.Whenever user taps on ok button i need to start a uiactivityIndicator and the alert has to disappear.So, that i can se only the activity indicator when user taps on Ok in Alert.How can i Achieve this .Here is my code:

```
             alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Deletion" message:@"You are done" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

[alert release];


         -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
      {
         action:@selector(otherButtonTitles);

//index = alertDone.cancelButtonIndex;
       [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
         if(buttonIndex==0) {

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector (activityFunctionForDeletion) withObject:nil];


    //alert.hidden=YES;
    myResults *byDateScreen = [[myResults alloc]initWithNibName:@"myResults" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:byDateScreen animated:YES];
    [byDateScreen dataDisplay];
    [byDateScreen release];
        [activity stopAnimating];
    [activity setHidden:YES];
    //[byDateScreen release];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys.I found the solution for my problem..
What i did is instead of writing
       [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; i  wrote it in the   ''activityFunctionForDeletion'' method.

so when i tap on ok the alert disappeared and activity starts animating.